# What is half level at Level 1?

Tags: dnd-4e

I was wondering what 1/2 level at level 1 is. I would assume it is 0 because you round down on fractions. But I had heard it was also just 1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**0**

Unless specifically instructed, you always round down in D&D. See page 11 of PHB1 for the full text of the rule.